# Can we return all category (not post) with Custom Query Filter?

Tags: wp-query, categories, meta-query

I wanted to make some sort of category grid using `elementor's` Custom Query Filter.

I will have a featured image and and post title.

I know ways to do it with a loop but that will be not applicable with elementor as I like to know if a wp query can return all taxonomy (category) as if they were posted.

something like this:

`add_action( 'elementor/query/my_custom_filter', function( $query ) {
        $args = array(
                   'taxonomy' => 'erfahrungsschatz',
                   'orderby' => 'name',
                   'order'   => 'ASC'
               );
    } );`

Post Type Slug : `projekt`

Taxonomy Slug: `erfahrungsschatz`

ELEMENTOR's [Custom Query Filter](https://developers.elementor.com/custom-query-filter/)